# Who out of George and Fred Weasley was born first?

Tags: harry-potter

Is there anything in the books about whether Fred or George is older?

Answer (score 7):

**Fred was born first.**

I don’t think this is explicitly mentioned in the books, but when somebody asked her this on Twitter, JK Rowling said that Fred was born first:

> .@Eowynlily Fred was born first.  I always thought that was obvious!
>
> — [@JKRowling on Twitter, 23 May 2015](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/602105708511961091)

(To this day, I’ve never been able to work out why this was “obvious”. The alphabetical ordering gives us a hint, but (1) that’s quite subtle, and (2) expecting Fred and George to follow predictable patterns is a recipe for egg on your face.)

Comment: Apparently Jo is right and it **was** obvious, since everyone else *guessed* Fred was older **correctly**!!! (additional question: How did you manage to get a tweet from Jo from 2 days **in the future!**) :P

Comment: @BMWurm - Hmm. His time machine appears to be little more than a typographical error. He's a phony. A big fat phony!

Comment: Since your answer contains a Word-of-god confirmation, I've zapped mine.

Comment: @Richard Hence the :P ... but you never know, maybe Jo or Alex or both used a time turner??